# jquery touchswipe plugin not working proeperly on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I'm developing a website where the scroll event's default is prevented and instead each scroll takes you down or up to the next "section".  This works really well on PC and some phones but on iOS the scrolling just becomes this jumbled up mess and quite frankly I'm out of ideas.

The scroll API for mobile I'm using is jquery touchSwipe
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

And the following code is the function that is supposed to do all the work.

```js
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $(window).swipe({
          swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            if (scrolling == false && direction === "down") {
              scrolling = true;
              scrollSection = Math.round($(window).scrollTop()/window.innerHeight);
              scrollTo_(event,sections[scrollSection-1]);
              setTimeout(function() {
                scrolling = false;
              }, 1000);
            }
            else if (scrolling == false && direction === "up") {
              scrolling = true;
              scrollSection = Math.round($(window).scrollTop()/window.innerHeight);
              scrollTo_(event,sections[scrollSection+1]);
              setTimeout(function() {
                scrolling = false;
              }, 1000);
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

If you have any questions by all means let me know and I will update this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js)?
In my web app last days I've worked on Jquery UI slider, that's didn't worked for mobiles, so after attaching that it get's worked.

Comment: Is that for swipes on mobile? And does it prevent scrolling you on iOS?